# JSTree, creating nodes, and javascript timeout

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree, nodes

I created a JSTree using json data. Initially, everything works as expected.

However, when I add nodes dynamically with a function using "create" (crrm plugin)

> jQuery("#mpTree").jstree("create",
>   parentNodeId, "last", { "attr" : {
>   "rel" : "assetNew", "id" :
>   "newNodeId"}, "data": "dataVarHere"}
>   ,function() {} , true);

Javascript times out if I go over 30ish subsequent nodes created in IE, 60ish in Mozilla. Chrome can handle the load without timeout.

Obviously, this is far from ideal. Is there any other way to create a bunch of nodes and add them to tree without excessive loading?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: By "timeout" you mean the browser complains about a slow script, right?

Comment: If I need to add a child to the root as well as other nodes when they are clicked using crrm plugin. What can I write instead to access the nodeID of the node on which the user has clicked ? I just need a generic substitute for parentNodeId in the create built-in function. This is what I tried but dint succeed. 

    $("#tree").click(function() {
    $("#tree").jstree("create", $(this.id), "inside",  { "data" : "new child node", "state" : "open"}, false, true);  
  
THanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're trying to use "create" to load the whole tree. I don't think it's intended (or optimised) for that (I think it's mainly for adding just one or two nodes to an existing tree).

I think the usual way to do it use **one of the data plugins (e.g. [JS_DATA](http://www.jstree.com/documentation/json_data)) to load your tree** initially.

Where is your data coming from? A database? If it's not already HTML, XML, or JSON, can you convert it to one of those?

Comment: My initial load of the tree is using Json data. However, we have a function to add a number of assets to a particular node/nodes of a tree (to see a visual structure of the management of data), and ultimately, save the relationship in our database. My current solution may involve manipulating the JSON Data, adding the nodes, and repainting the tree, however I need to know which nodes are open/closed and reopen them, which sounds like too much of a hassle.

Comment: OK. Have you looked at using the cookies plugin to remember what was open? http://www.jstree.com/documentation/cookies

Comment: Like you said, create was not the proper way to handle the list. I changed to JSON (had to reestructure the data) and it loads like a charm.